# How can I generate a list in a functional style in kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, functional-programming

I am working on a function which will receive a list of bookings, and each booking contains a unix-timestamp.

I am using the function for a viewpager in which each page contains a recyclerview, so I want to create a list of days, for all days between the current day and the day of the last booking made.

Each day has its day and a list of bookings which can also be empty.

I want to create the list of days in a functional style, I don't really know how, but I am pretty sure kotlin has some nice feature hidden somewhere for me to do it.

Thank you in advance. :)

*Here is how my function looks like, and the models I am using in it.*

```kotlin
data class Day(val date:Date, val bookings: List<Bookink>)
data class Booking(val id:String, val time:Long, val user:User)

fun dates(bookings: List<Booking>): List<Day> {
    val lastDate = Date(bookings.last().time)
    val days = ArrayList<Day>()
    val cal = GregorianCalendar()
    cal.time = Date()

    while (cal.time.before(lastDate)) {
        days.add(Day(cal.time, bookings.filter { (Date(it.time) == cal.time) }))
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    }

    return days
}
```

Comment: This is quite details description how to build date range in functional way: https://www.netguru.com/codestories/traversing-through-dates-with-kotlin-range-expressions . I'm sorry for sending a link instead of solution, it would be too much for a comment

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? A shorter form of your solution?

Comment: Thank you @Eugene this looks interesting

Comment: @ChristianB yes I am trying to learn the functional style, and I want to avoid loops and stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to see a more functional solution to your problem, you would need to create a sequence with a one day step until the end date.
After that, each day is mapped to corresponding Day object with filtered list of bookings.

Please note that I have used a more modern (and preferred) way of working with dates in Java and Kotlin - `LocalDate` class. I have included a function to convert milliseconds to LocalDate - `Long.toLocalDate`

```
fun dates(bookings: List<Booking>): List<Day> {
    val startDate = LocalDate.now()
    val endDate = bookings.last().time.toLocalDate()

    return generateSequence(startDate) { it.plusDays(1) }
       .takeWhile { it.isBefore(endDate) }
       .map { day -> Day(day, bookings.filter { it.time.toLocalDate() == day }) }.toList()
}

private fun Long.toLocalDate(): LocalDate {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(this)
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDate()
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly the kind of crisp I was looking for ! :-)

Comment: Nice answer... You could make `dates` an extension function of `List<Booking>`, would be even more functional in *the Kotlin way*. +1 anyway here.